# Анимации(canvas)

Tags: javascript

На экране шарик со случайным цветом,который двигается в разных направлениях и отбивается от стен.
Каждые 200 миллисекунд появляется ещё 1 шарик, у которого есть случайный цвет и двигается в случайном направлении.
Максимальное количество шариков не должно превышать 20.

Помогите пожалуйста понять и реализовать задачу.

```js
class GraphicTools{
    constructor(){
        this.canvas=document.querySelector('canvas')
        this.ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    }
}
//===================================================
class Ball extends GraphicTools{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.x=Math.random()*this.canvas.width;
        this.y=Math.random()*this.canvas.height;
        this.z=20;
        this.dx=Math.random()*2
        this.dy=Math.random()*2
        this.a=Math.random()*255
        this.b=Math.random()*255
        this.c=Math.random()*255
        this.col=`rgb(${this.a},${this.b},${this.c})`
      }
    move(){
          
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height)
        if(this.x>this.canvas.width||this.x<0){
            this.dx=-this.dx
        }
        if(this.y>this.canvas.height||this.y<0){
             this.dy=-this.dy
        }
        this.x+=this.dx
        this.y+=this.dy
        this.paint()
        
        
    }
    paint(){
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.fillStyle=this.col
        this.ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.z,0,6.28)
        this.ctx.fill()
        this.ctx.closePath()
     }
    
 }
 //=================================================
 class Animation{
    static start(){
        let ball=new Ball()
        ball.paint()
         // for(let i=0;i<20;i++){
         //    setInterval(function(){
         //    ball.paint()
         //    },200)
         // }
       setInterval(function(){
            ball.move();
       },2)
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas height="600" width="1366" style="background: yellowgreen"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ваша задача в классе Animation создать не один шар и двигать его, а создать массив для шаров и двигать все шары из массива разом. Сначала у вас будет в массиве один шар, вам же надо постепенно с помощью еще одного интервала увеличить их количество до 20 штук. Ну и рандомизировать начальные цвет и направление в конструкторе шара.

Comment: @Alex Krasslet, есть ведь такой объект: ```ball=new Ball()```, можно ли сделать ```push()``` в него используя ещё и цикл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вносить минимум изменений в ваш код, то это должно выглядеть как в коде ниже. Переносится код очищения canvas в GraphicTools поскольку вызвать его надо только один раз в начале рисования всех шаров. А дальше делается просто массив `let balls = [];` и работаем со всеми шарами одновременно. Все основные изменения в пределах класса Animation.

```js
class GraphicTools{
    constructor(){
        this.canvas=document.querySelector('canvas')
        this.ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    }
    
    clear(){
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height)
    }
}
//===================================================
class Ball extends GraphicTools{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.x=Math.random()*this.canvas.width;
        this.y=Math.random()*this.canvas.height;
        this.z=20;
        this.dx=Math.random()*2
        this.dy=Math.random()*2
        this.a=Math.random()*255
        this.b=Math.random()*255
        this.c=Math.random()*255
        this.col=`rgb(${this.a},${this.b},${this.c})`
      }
    move(){
        if(this.x>this.canvas.width||this.x<0){
            this.dx=-this.dx
        }
        if(this.y>this.canvas.height||this.y<0){
             this.dy=-this.dy
        }
        this.x+=this.dx
        this.y+=this.dy
        this.paint()
        
        
    }
    paint(){
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.fillStyle=this.col
        this.ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.z,0,6.28)
        this.ctx.fill()
        this.ctx.closePath()
     }
    
 }
 //=================================================
 class Animation{
    static start(){
        let balls = [new Ball()];
        let gt = new GraphicTools();
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            balls.push(new Ball());
            if(balls.length >= 20) clearInterval(interval);
        }, 200)
        
       setInterval(function(){
            gt.clear()
            balls.forEach(ball => { 
                ball.move(), ball.paint()
            });
       },2)
    }
}

Animation.start()
```

```html
<canvas height="600" width="1366" style="background: yellowgreen"></canvas>
```

Comment: спасибо за пояснение, ответ исчерпывающий

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
class Game{
    constructor(){
            this.balls = [];

        //bind events to this context
            this.addBall = this.addBall.bind(this);
            this.render = this.render.bind(this);

        //timer for generate new ball
            this.timer = setInterval(this.addBall, 200);

        //start draw loop
            this.render();
    }

    addBall(){
        //recursion condition
            if(this.balls.length >= 20){
            if(this.timer)
                    clearInterval(this.timer);

            return;
            }

        //generate new ball
            this.balls.push(new Ball(
            genRandom(opts.radius/2, w - opts.radius/2), 
            genRandom(opts.radius/2, h - opts.radius/2), 
            genRandom(0, Math.PI*2)
            ));
    }

    render(){
        //draw background
            ctx.fillStyle = opts.bgColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        //redraw balls
            this.balls.forEach( (ball) => {
            ball.update();
            ball.render();
            } );

        //loop render function
            requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
    }
}
```

Полный пример:
https://codepen.io/HTMLProgrammer/pen/qBdoXor

Comment: а возможен ли вариант попроще?

Comment: @VahanMuradyan, а куда еще проще можно?